# how to handle unexpected 'alert' in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, exception, automated-tests, mocha.js

**PS:** *driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); is not working*

Well , I want to automate testing of webpage which shows  **random alerts***

```
*random alerts :JavaScript Alert which are not controlled and can appear any time
```

so I dont know where to put `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()`because the occurrence of alert is not known in advance.

So kindly help me.. Here is simple mocha selenium test... I have commented out the alert.accept() part..

I want to know how to handle

> UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text :}

once in for all....

I read the selenium docs but couldn't find any...

here is my code

```
describe( 'handling alerts' , function(done){      
        after(function(done){
               return driver.quit();
            done(); 
        });

        it( 'should check title ', function(done){
                driver.get("https://www.google.in");
                driver.findElement(By.id("q")); 

                driver.get("https://jsfiddle.net/cwthh0y7/");
               // driver.switchTo().alert().accept();   

                driver.getTitle().then(function(title){  

                    assert.equal(title, "Edit fiddle - JSFiddle");
                    done();   
                });



        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set capabilities while defining your driver object.

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver.html#UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR

Refer this link on how to set Capabilities. This will help you define a generic behavior when your alerts are intermittent.

Comment: awwwww ... defining a generic behavior would be a *great help* thank you